# Error when fitting 3D convolutional neural network

Tags: python-3.x, keras, conv-neural-network

I am trying to train a convolutional neural network on google colab for a medical classification problem. The data set is 89 256x256x256 images for training and 11 for testing. When I try to make my model train it gives me the following error:

```py
import keras
from keras import optimizers
import keras.models
from keras.models import Sequential
import keras.layers
from keras.layers.convolutional import Conv3D
from keras.layers.convolutional import MaxPooling3D
from keras.layers import Dropout
from keras.layers import Flatten
from keras.layers import Dense
from keras import metrics
model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv3D(64, kernel_size=(3,3,3),
                 activation='relu',
                 input_shape=(10,1,256,256,256)))
model.add(Conv3D(64, (2,2,2), activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling3D(pool_size=(2,2,2)))
model.add(Dropout(0.25))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(128, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(2, activation='softmax'))

opt=keras.optimizers.Adam(lr=0.001, beta_1=0.9, beta_2=0.999, epsilon=None, decay=0.0, amsgrad=False)
model.compile(opt, loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['mae','acc'])
model.fit(x=train_data, y=train_labels,epochs=100, batch_size=10, verbose=2 ,callbacks=None, validation_split=0.0, validation_data=(validation_data,validation_labels), shuffle=True)
```

This is the error i get:

> ValueError: Input 0 is incompatible with layer conv3d_56: expected ndim=5, found ndim=6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you are using channels first data_format, your `input_shape` argugment to the first Conv3D layer  should be `(CHANNELS, HEIGHT, WIDTH, DEPTH)`. But your input shape tuple has length of 5, and that is not what Conv3D layer expecting. Assuming the batch_size(of 10) is specified by mistake, making the following changes should fix the problem

```py
model.add(Conv3D(64, kernel_size=(3,3,3),
                 activation='relu',
                 input_shape=(1,256,256,256)))
```

### Edit

If you are using channels_last data-format your `input_shape` should be `(HEIGHT, WIDTH, DEPTH, CHANNELS)`. And assuming your images have 1 channels, the above line should be,

```py
model.add(Conv3D(64, kernel_size=(3,3,3),
                 activation='relu',
                 input_shape=(256,256,256, 1)))
```

Comment: I tried to use your code but still throws eror:
'''ValueError: Negative dimension size caused by subtracting 3 from 1 for 'conv3d_63/convolution' (op: 'Conv3D') with input shapes: [?,1,256,256,256], [3,3,3,256,64].'''

Comment: And what do you mean by saying:"Assuming the batch_size(of 10) is specified by mistake, "?

Comment: 10 from `input_shape=(10,1,256,256,256)`. You are getting the error message because you are using channels_last data format.

Comment: I celebrated too early :(, I started the training of the model and i left(since it is likely to take a lot of time to train). When i Got back it gave me another error

Comment: ValueError: Error when checking input: expected conv3d_5_input to have 5 dimensions, but got array with shape (89, 256, 256, 256)

Comment: add line `train_data = train_data.reshape(-1, 256, 256, 256,1)` before calling `model.fit`.

Comment: Still error:
ValueError: Error when checking target: expected dense_18 to have shape (2,) but got array with shape (1,)

Comment: This is because you haven't encoded(one_hot encoding) your `train_labels`. Or change the last layer to `Dense(1, activation="sigmoid")` and loss to `binary_crossentropy`